# subset square matrix A based on condition of square matrix A and square matrix B

Tags: r

I tried to subset a square matrix A (58x58) based on values in (square matrix A >0 & square matrix B <0.05). Square matrix A and Square matrix B are of the same column and row and of the same size (58x58).

my code:
df<- A[A>0 & B<0.05]
output <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(df))

However, it returns a vector [1:1620] instead of 58x58. Can anyone help fix this?
Thank you so much !

Comment: What do you mean by "subsetting a matrix"? If you remove the elements that do not satisfy the condition, you can't have a matrix of the same size at the end. Perhaps what you want to do is to replace some elements with 0 or NA?

Comment: Yes, perhaps you want to do `A[A>0 & B<0.05] <- NA`

Comment: yes, this is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(A, A > 0 & B < 0.05, NA)
```